# GeoDjango GDALException - OGR failure

Tags: python, django, gdal, geodjango

After installing GeoDjango, I wanted to create a 'Location' object in the admin panel which uses an address and a point on a map. After submitting the form, I get an error like so...

```
GDALException at /admin/maps/location/add/
OGR failure.
```

I have tried looking at similar questions, [like here](https://github.com/dulacp/heroku-buildpack-geodjango/issues/8), but none of the solutions have worked. Additionally, searching for 'unable to load PROJ.4 library' (first traceback line) didn't come with any success.

Any help would be appreciated! - Let me know if I should update this question with my settings.py or other relevant files.

Full traceback:

```
GDAL_ERROR 6: Unable to load PROJ.4 library (libproj.dylib), creation of OGRCoordinateTransformation failed.
Internal Server Error: /admin/maps/location/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 551, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 224, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1508, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1408, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1440, in _changeform_view
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 183, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 175, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 384, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 402, in _clean_fields
    value = field.clean(value)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/fields.py", line 75, in clean
    geom.transform(self.srid)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/geometry.py", line 527, in transform
    g.transform(ct)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/geometries.py", line 408, in transform
    capi.geom_transform_to(self.ptr, sr.ptr)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/prototypes/errcheck.py", line 119, in check_errcode
    check_err(result, cpl=cpl)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/error.py", line 73, in check_err
    raise e(msg)
GDALException: OGR failure.
```

Edit:
Added my models.py and admin.py for Location

models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.conf import settings
from . import utils

COUNTRIES=((0,'UK'),(1,'USA'),(2,'CA'),(3,'AUS'),(4,'JP'),(5,'FR'))
class Location(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=120,verbose_name='House name/number',blank=True)
    first_addr=models.CharField(max_length=45,verbose_name='Address line 1',blank=False)
    second_addr=models.CharField(max_length=45,verbose_name='Address line 2',blank=True)
    town=models.CharField(max_length=45,verbose_name='Town/City',blank=False)
    state=models.CharField(max_length=45,verbose_name='State/Province',blank=False)
    zip_code=models.CharField(max_length=12,verbose_name='Postal/Zip Code',blank=False)
    country=models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Country',blank=False,null=False,choices=COUNTRIES)
    point=models.PointField(default='POINT (0 0)',srid=4326)
    dt_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    dt_updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Location'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    @property
    def longitude(self):
        return self.point[0]
    @property
    def latitude(self):
        return self.point[1]
```

Admin.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from maps.models import *

class LocationAdmin(admin.OSMGeoAdmin):
    model = Location
    list_display = ['name','first_addr','second_addr','town','state','zip_code','country','longitude','latitude','dt_created','dt_updated']
    search_fields = ['first_addr','second_addr','town','state','zip_code']

admin.site.register(Location,LocationAdmin)
```

Comment: Please add your `Location` source code from `models.py` and `admin.py`.

Comment: @Udi Have added the source for models and admin

Comment: how did you install this?  I found getting geodjango dependencies working in ubuntu and osx such a pain in the backside that I moved to using an anaconda environment.  Made it _much_ easier to get the correct dependencies installed.

Comment: Are you using Windows? I would guess this is an installation problem.

Comment: @Udi I'm using Mac

Comment: @jayt Were you able to solve this issue? Even i am using mac for development and Ubuntu for deployment. The issue that i get says **OGR Failure** with message as - _Error during template rendering_.

Comment: @jason, you can install QGIS and hook the necessary libraries to Django in your settings, instead of installing them in your virtual environment.

Answer (score 3):

```
import os
if os.name == 'nt':
    import platform
    OSGEO4W = r"C:\OSGeo4W"
    if '64' in platform.architecture()[0]:
        OSGEO4W += "64"
    assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
    os.environ['OSGEO4W_ROOT'] = OSGEO4W
    os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = "C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal-data" 
    os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\proj"
    GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = r'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal204'
    os.environ['PATH'] = OSGEO4W + r"\bin;" + os.environ['PATH']
```

Adding these lines into the setting.py works for me. But when you adding the GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH check what are the gdal libraries you have and add one of the gdal library like 'gdal204'

Answer (score 0):

This error will fixed if you add following command at the top of your setting.py file

```
    if os.name == 'nt':
    import platform
    OSGEO4W = r"C:\OSGeo4W"
    if '64' in platform.architecture()[0]:
        OSGEO4W += "64"
    assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
    os.environ['OSGEO4W_ROOT'] = OSGEO4W
    os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\gdal"
    os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\proj"
    os.environ['PATH'] = OSGEO4W + r"\bin;" + os.environ['PATH']
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it didn't work. Can you checkout my problem: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60139673/geo-django-gdal-exception-ogr-failure

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows OS and some settings file please use following line:

> GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = r'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal300'

I am using this for my Django based app.

Comment: when using ubuntu it shows error like : django.contrib.gis.gdal.error.GDALException: OGR failure.